# Query with CASE WHEN / LAST_DAY is not giving any output

Tags: sql, oracle

Running below query and not getting the output. Can someone please tell whats wrong in it?

```
Select distinct (table.datex)
from table
where table.datex = 
(
  CASE when extract( day from sysdate) >=19
    then last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1))
    else last_day(add_months(sysdate, -2))
  END
)
```

### Sample data

| Datex | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 30-JUN-21 | A |
| 31-MAY-21 | B |
| 29-JUN-21 | C |

### Expected result

| Datex |
| --- |
| 30-JUN-21 |

When I am passing the value hard-coded(calculated by the case) to where clause it's working fine, but when I apply the case it's not working. No error. No output is coming.

Comment: well, maybe the `WHERE`  condition does not match any rows?

Comment: I'm sure you get at least some error message? Are you sure you do have matching records in the table? And did you seriously name your table "table"? That's probably the biggest problem and you need to escape that name, because "table" is a sql key word. How to escape correctly depends on your database. Is it sql server or oracle or mysql? Please tag. I'd suggest to try `[table]`.

Comment: Add sample data.

Comment: Yes, I do have matching records in the table and it's just a sample name of the table. When I am Passing the value hard-coded(calculated by the case) to where clause ..it's working fine but when I apply the case it's not working..No error..No output is coming.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (last_day, add_months, sysdate etc are all product specific.)

Comment: It's a Oracle..

Comment: Sample data -                                                                             
Datex             ID
30-JUN-21    A
31-MAY-21    B
29-JUN-21     C

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: `distinct` is **not** a function. It always applies to all columns in the select list. Enclosing one of the columns with parentheses won't change anything and is useless. `distinct (a),b` is the same as `distinct a,(b)` or `distinct a,b`

Answer (score 1):

### Date or datetime?

Oracle's `LAST_DAY` doesn't do what the name suggests, and the docs (https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/LAST_DAY.html#GUID-296C7C02-7FB9-4AAC-8927-6A79320CE0C6) fail to explain that, too.

Unlike several other DBMS Oracle doesn't have a date type. It only has a datetime type and they even call that inappropriately `DATE`. This means that a "date" in Oracle always has a time part. A date with its time part set to 00:00:00 can be considered a day's midnight (i.e. the very beginning of the day) or the whole day.

The function `SYSDATE` gives us a date in the sense of the `DATE` datatype, not in the sense of a real day, i.e. it gives us the datetime of "now", e.g. 2021-07-20 14:38:00. `ADD_MONTHS` changes the month in that datetime (and sometimes the year and sometimes even the day), i.e. leaves the time part untouched. `LAST_DAY`, too, changes the date part to get to the last day of the month, but leaves the time part untouched.

Your `CASE` expression hence results in something like `TIMESTAMP '2021-07-20 14:38:00'` and not in `DATE '2021-07-20'` as one might expect.

You say that you tried your query with the date you computed wth your case expression, and it worked. Did you compute the resulting day in your head or with a query? If the latter: The tool you are using may be set to only display a datetime's date part and omit the time part. This would explain why you only saw 30-JUN-21 when checking the `CASE` expression.

### Solution

Truncate the datetime down to a whole day

```
Select distinct datex
from mytable 
where (extract(day from sysdate) >=19 and datex = trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -1))))
   or (extract(day from sysdate) < 19 and datex = trunc(last_day(add_months(sysdate, -2))))
```

It doesn't matter whether you apply `TRUNC` late as in my example or right away on `SYSDATE` (with `TRUNC(SYSDATE)`) by the way. The only aim is to get rid of the time part at some point in the expression.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `case` in `where` clauses. Boolean logic can handle that.
And take a look if it is really the condition you want

```
Select distinct datex
from your_table 
where 
(
   extract(day from sysdate) >=19
   and datex = last_day(add_months(sysdate,-1)) 
)
or 
(
   extract(day from sysdate) < 19
   and datex = last_day(add_months(sysdate,-2))
)
```